# Graphical representation of an app using Visual Studio 2008 Professional edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, flowchart, representation

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2008 Professional edition to create a graphical representation of an application?  What I am looking for is a flowchart or other design graph that shows each program in the app and how they relate to other programs and files in the app.  I can create one using Visio, but wanted to know if there is something built into Visual Studio that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In the solution explorer, right click on your project, and choose Add->New Item...

In the Project Items, add a "Class Diagram".

This lets you create a class diagram, which can be used to show inheritance and other relationships between your classes.